# invalid escape character "\\" was specified in a LIKE predicate

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, jpa-2.0, openjpa, sql-like

i'm getting this error message with my query.. i'm using openjpa and sql server for my database...

this is my query:

```
public static List<ProcesosGeneralEntity> getALLbyProductor(String productor){
           Query q = entityManager.createQuery("select a from ProcesosGeneralEntity a where a.productor like :productor ");
            q.setParameter("productor", '%'+productor+'%');
            List<ProcesosGeneralEntity>resultado=q.getResultList();
            List<ProcesosGeneralEntity>result2=new ArrayList<ProcesosGeneralEntity>(resultado);
            return result2;

        }
```

Comment: It sounds like OpenJPA is escaping a product string incorrectly, as one source I found states that the escape character for Oracle Database is `\`, so to escape a quote you do `\'`, and to escape a backslash you do `\\`. Whereas in SQL Server, the escape character for a single quote is another quote, as in `''`. So it sounds like you have a `productor` string that contains a single `\`, which OpenJPA is escaping to `\\`. The solution may be that you need to specify that your `openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary` configuration is set to `sqlserver`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case my comment above is correct, I am submitting this as a tentative or possible answer.

Different database software behaves slightly differently, the [ANSI SQL Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Standardization) does not cover all behavioral quirks of SQL, and so things like escape characters in strings differ between implementations. In SQL Server, escaping a quote mark is done with another quote mark, so to print the string "Alice's dog", one needs to use use, in SQL, the string `'Alice''s dog'`. In Oracle Database, the escape character is a backslash, so to print that same string, you instead use `'Alice\'s dog'`. Escape characters themselves need to be able to be printed, so in Oracle Database, to print the string "R2\D2", you need to enter the string `'R2\\D2'`.

The problem you are having *appears* to be that it thinks it is talking to an Oracle Database, and thus defaulted to the latter behavior, and used `\\` to quote a single `\`, instead of leaving it be. SQL Server then had a hiccup on this option or some-such. I'm not sure why it threw it back, to be honest.

Regardless, according to the OpenJPA manual's section [4. Database Support - Chapter 4. JDBC](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.4/apache-openjpa-1.0.4/docs/manual/ref_guide_dbsetup_dbsupport.html) you need to specify the correct DBDictionary. The DBDictionary specifies settings like which escape characters to use in which cases, and other non-standard options that are not uniform across all database systems supported.

The solution appears to be that in the configuration file for your software, you must specify something like:

`<property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="sqlserver"/>`

Comment: you are right, thank you!! i had the dictionary set to "mysql" i changed it to :

 <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLServerDictionary"/> 

now i do not get the error message :)!